# Windows 10 Offline Files will not Sync

Tags: windows-server-2012, high-availability, folder-redirection, windows-10, offline-files

Brand new domain using Windows 10 workstations and Server 2012 R2 Domain Controllers. Standard folder redirection GPO

Picture of the issue:

[image]

Files are being redirected to a windows 2012 r2 high availability cluster. As seen in the picture we are unable to sync these files.

**File Share Settings**

- Access-based enumeration - enabled
- Continuos availiblity - disabled
- Allow Caching of share - enabled
- Encrypt data access - enabled

Comment: Have you enabled offline files in Sync Center on the Windows 10 clients?

Comment: Offline Files in sync center is enabled by default. I can deactivate offline files but then I have to retrieve the unsynced files from the c:\windows\csc\ folder and then it makes things a little difficult for laptop users not being able to undock without losing access to their files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved.

Turns out my Users$ share permissions were too restrictive for Sync Center (and MS Publisher). I had Create Folders, and Traverse Folder allowed, I needed to add List Folder, Read Attributes, Read Extended Attributes.